# Analytic (inverse sampling variance) weight in stata

Tags: regression, weighted-regression

I have a question about using `aweight` in regression in Stata. I have school level data (mostly percentages) but I want also to take school size into consideration. According to Stata manual:

> aweights, or analytic weights, are weights that are inversely proportional to the variance of an observation; that is the variance of the $j$th observation is assumed to be $\sigma ^2/w_j$, where $w_j$ are the weights. Typically, the observation represents averages and the weights are the number of elements that gave rise to the average.

Since my data are school averages, it seems to be the most fitting way to incorporate school size into the regression. But someone points out if I want to use school size I could just include it in the regression. Could someone help explain what is the difference, using weights or include them in the specification, and when aweights should be used?

Comment: Since `aweight` is terminology specific to Stata, and most people will not be users of that software, you will get more attention and perhaps more help by explaining what an `aweight` is.

Comment: @whuber I have made some edits in the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Are these school averages explanatory or response variables? What exactly do they represent--averages based on students in schools, or averages over groups of schools, perhaps--and what is the reason for supposing that school size needs explicitly to be modeled in your analysis?

Comment: These school averages are explanatory variables. The outcome variable is a school quality rating point. Each observation is a school, so the averages are things like % of Free or Reduced lunch student, % hispanic students, etc. I guess the reason for putting school size in the model is just to say, school size is related with ratings, controlled for other things.